# Call command in Unix Make

Tags: unix, makefile

I'm trying to understand a makefile, can anyone tell me what the following line does:

```
@echo cp -f --preserve=mode,timestamps $(call $1,$<) $(call $1,$@)
```

Especially I don't get what is the significance of `$1` and `call` here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know what this does, since it's completely out of context.

It looks to me like this value is supposed to be passed to another instance of `$(call ...)`.  So for example if your makefile has:

```
QUOTE = '$1'
COPY = @echo cp -f --preserve=mode,timestamps $(call $1,$<) $(call $1,$@)
```

then later you would see something like:

```
foo: bar ; $(call COPY,QUOTE)
```

The first call would expand to the `COPY` value with `$1` replaced with `QUOTE`, so it would be:

```
@echo cp -f --preserve=mode,timestamps $(call QUOTE,bar) $(call QUOTE,foo)
```

then that gets expanded, and you end up with:

```
@echo cp -f --preserve=mode,timestamps 'bar' 'foo'
```

But without more information we can't say more.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not get what 'call' is used for. I read the make manual but im still confused

Comment: Well, you should probably ask THAT question then.  This is not a particularly good example for learning what call does, IMO.  Call lets you define your own functions (sort of) that take arguments.  You put the body of the "function" into a variable, using `$1`, `$2`, etc. as placeholders for the first, second, etc. arguments.  Then when you want to "run" the function, you pass the name of the variable plus argument values to `$(call ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'call' command is a GNU extension in GNUmake; it is not supported in POSIX make or most other makes.  It basically expands a macro with arguments.  Something like

```
$(call A,b,c,d)
```

will expand the macro `A` with the arguments `b`, `c`, and `d`.  The arguments are assigned to the temporary macros `$(1)`, `$(2)`, ... which may be present in the definition of `A`

See [the GNUmake documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function)